# Transfer textbox value to multiple select with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want pass a phone number from a textbox when user write on it and click add. They can also add values from other multiple select box too. Value need to be removed when user click on remove button. How can I do this with Jquery ? Can anyone help please ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
     
  // Add remove elements from select box
  $('#btn-add').click(function(){
   $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
     $('#select-to').append("value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"");
    $(this).remove();
   });
  });
  $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
   $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
    $('#select-from').append("value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"");
    $(this).remove();
   });
  });
  
  //Charecter count for message
  $("#send_sms").charCount();
  
 });

Comment: Passing from the textbox to what?

Comment: to a multiple select box

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dmazza/FFg5U/ Now just put in your html and click update, then update your original post with the link.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start:

```
$("#add-button").on('click', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); //just to be sure the button doesn't trigger a submit or something
  var phoneInput = $("#phone").val(); 
  // write code here for what you need to do with the phone number
});
```

You can do this for the remove button as well, and you can bind to the `change` event for the multiple select, and do a similar thing again.

To set the value in a textbox, use `$("#textbox-id").val(newValue);`

http://docs.jquery.com/Val

http://api.jquery.com/on/

If you can create a jsFiddle, I'll be happy to look at it and make suggestions if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I,m giving it a try right now. What I want is to add values from text box to a multiple select box when user write on it and click add. And this can be removed from multiple select when user click on remove

Comment: Hello Man can u do just another fever ? How can I display the value in the multiple select box ?